# Error: Expected expression before 'String' And too few arguments to function 'strcmp'

Tags: c, string, binary-search, strcmp

I've been trying to finish a part of our program for our groupings but whenever I try to compile there's always an error for this part of the code.

```
int
Binary_Search(String key, String Name[], int nElements)
{
    /* Implement the body of this function. */
    
    int position;
    int begin = 0; 
    int end = String Name - 1; //Error: Expected expression before 'String'
    int result = 0;
    
    while(begin <= end) 
    {
        position = (begin + end) / 2;
        if(result = strcmp(String Name, nElements) == 0) //Error: Expected expression 
                                                 //before 'String'
                                                 // too few arguments to 
                                                 // Function 'strcmp'
            return position;
    
        else if(result < 0)
            begin = position + 1;
    
        else
            end = position - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `String`? Where do you get the errors? And please [edit] your question to not only include the full and complete error output, copy-pasted as text, but also please try to include a [mcve] that causes the errors, and add comments on the lines where you get them.

Comment: As a hint about your problem, please go back to your text-books (or get some if you don't have any) and read more about arrays and pointers.

Comment: sorry about that @Someprogrammerdude, I'm quite new to programming, and with online classes, it's a bit hard for me to learn about programming

Comment: Two probs with `strcmp(String Name, nElements)` a) you must not mention the type when passing an argument, b) the second argument must also be a string, not an integer.

Comment: Another problem is the boolean value assiged to `result`. It can't be `< 0` as tested further down (although the return value from `strcmp()` can). I think you should study `strcmp()` a bit more.

Comment: Also `int end = String Name - 1;` you should not mention the type, and, the result can't be assigned to `int`. The function must return a value from all control paths too. There are lots of errors in the code, go through them in order.

Comment: Take it slow, and I really recommend that you get some books to read. Don't try to rush into things, and learn about a concept fully before moving on to the next. The code you show shows a lack of understanding about some very important concepts, and you need to take a few steps back to relearn them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `end` should be set to `nElements-1`.

Then this line has several problems:

```
if(result = strcmp(String Name, nElements) == 0)
```

The most obvious is that it should be `strcmp(Name, nElements)`, assuming `String` is some horrid typedef for `char*` (from some bad class like CS-50?).

Also, `nElements` is an `int`, not a string, so it can't be compared with a string... supposedly you meant to do something like `strcmp(Name[position], key)`.

Another problem is that `result` gets assigned the result of the expression `strcmp(...) == 0` (which gives `1` or `0`) rather than the result of `strcmp` (`<0`, or `==0`, or `>0`) as you intended. It is bad practice to use `=` inside control/loop statements for this very reason, it always leads to bugs. You should change the code to this:

```
result = strcmp(Name[position], key);

if(result == 0)
    return position;
else if(result < 0)
    begin = position + 1;
else // if result > 0
    end = position - 1;
```

Comment: Summary: you can't program by "take a chance"/trial and error. You must actually know what every line you write does, there's no guessing.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have string data type in c.
Try using char array to solve your issue. Also strcmp is used to compare char array(i.e. strings) not string with int.

Comment: This is pretty likely from the horrible CS-50 class where Harvard uni teaches students to use bad practice `typedef char* String;`.

Comment: Then it's fine but you cannot compare string with int using string cmp